# plsql to_date function giving ORA-03001: unimplemented feature

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two string parameters which are holding  dates in this format `"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"`.I am trying to getting datas between  two dates so i am using to_date function in oracle sql.But i am getting this error `ORA-03001: unimplemented feature`. This is how i am getting the datas:

```
...
ops.last_update_date between :to_date(startDate,'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss') and :to_date(endDate,'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss') 

...
```

Comment: Why are there `:`s?

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/improve-sql-query-performance-by-using-bind-variables  I need to modify this code. It is not my code but these are bind variables i think.

Comment: Are you sure about `HH`, which is 12-hour format? It would also require `AM/PM`. Otherwise it might be `HH24` for 24-hour format.

Comment: `mi` for minutes

Comment: So it should be `dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss`

Comment: Then it would be `ops.last_update_date between :startDate and :endDate` - one benefit of bind variables is that you don't need to take care much about data type conversions. Or maybe `ops.last_update_date between to_date(:startDate,'dd.MM.yyyy HH24:mi:ss') and to_date(:endDate,'dd.MM.yyyy HH24:mi:ss')`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit it worked. Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:` syntax should be used on the bind variables and not on the function wrapping then:

```sql
ops.last_update_date BETWEEN to_date(:startDate,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                     AND     to_date(:endDate,  'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

*Note: In the format model, you need `HH24` for a 24-hour clock and `MI` for minutes and, for the numeric format models, it is case insensitive.*

If you pass the values as `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data types (rather than strings) then it should just be:

```sql
ops.last_update_date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
```